# Query to get third highest marks

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I have a student_table table with two columns student_name(with uniqe constraint),student_marks.  From this table, I need to get the record of the student who has the 3rd highest marks.

I tried this, but it's incorrect:

```
select * from student_table orderby(marks) enum(marks)=3;
```

How do I correct this query?

Comment: is student_name unique? do you have multiple marks for 1 student?

Comment: How do you want to handle ties, if permitted?  E.g., two students have marks of 100, three have marks of 98, and five have marks of 95?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very simple solution

```
select *
from marks
order by marks desc
limit 2,1
```

with limit you can use offset and length. Here offset is set to two because it starts from 0. For third record. And 1 is the limit.

Here is another solution

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * from marks order by marks desc");
mysql_data_seek($res, 2);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `student_table` ORDER BY marks DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the 3rd record:

```
SELECT * FROM student_table ORDER BY marks DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

Have a read about the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) command.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM Student_Table ORDER BY Marks LIMIT 2, 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it gives 3 records not the third record?i need to get only third record.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from students_table orderby marks limit 2,1
```

Check this url to more about limit http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: Thanks,can u explain the answer.

Comment: can you go through url I given in my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Use Below query**
**QUERY** : select * from student_table where marks in (select marks from student_table group by marks order by marks desc limit 2,1);

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return all records for students in third place, regardless of how many students are tied for first, second, or third place.

```
SELECT student_table.name, student_table.marks
  FROM student_table
 WHERE student_table.primary_key IN (   SELECT ranked.primary_key
                                          FROM student_table ranked
                                     LEFT JOIN student_table others
                                               ON ranked.marks < others.marks
                                      GROUP BY 1
                                        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT others.marks) + 1 = 3)
```

For example, if `student_table` looks like this:

```
+---------+-------+
| name    | marks |
+---------+-------+
| Alpha   |   100 |
| Able    |   100 |
| Bravo   |    98 |
| Baker   |    98 |
| Bone    |    98 |
| Charlie |    93 | <-- 3rd place by marks
| Chimp   |    93 | <-- 3rd place by marks
| Delta   |    85 |
| Echo    |    80 |
| Ebert   |    80 |
+---------+-------+
```

the query will yield:

```
+---------+-------+
| name    | marks |
+---------+-------+
| Charlie |    93 |
| Chimp   |    93 |
+---------+-------+
```

As an aside, the query would be a little easier if MySQL supported DENSE_RANK(), but you can simulate that function with subqueries as above.